# I have a "ghost" velocity in simulation, and I cannot track down where it is coming from

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics, rapier, rapier-3d

I am creating a simulation of a roller conveyor system in Rapier js (vanilla js, with Three.js).

in order to simulate the rollers, I have created many cylinder-shaped objects rotated on their side:

```
roller = {
            visible:roller_sequence.visible,
            enable:"enable",
            speed:"speed",
            acceleration:"accel",
            speed_feedback:0,
            current_speed:"p "+position_number+" current speed",
            position_number:position_number,
            length:roller_sequence.length,
            radius:0.025,
            local_position: new THREE.Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z),
            local_rotation: new THREE.Quaternion(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z, rotation.w),
            position: new THREE.Vector3(absolute.position.x, absolute.position.y, absolute.position.z),
            rotation: new THREE.Quaternion(absolute.rotation.x, absolute.rotation.y, absolute.rotation.z, absolute.rotation.w),
            parent:roller_sequence.parent
        }

let rigidBodyDesc = RAPIER.RigidBodyDesc.kinematicPositionBased()
        .setTranslation(roller.position.x, roller.position.y, roller.position.z)
        .setRotation(new emulation.physics.Rapier.Quaternion(roller.rotation.x, roller.rotation.y, roller.rotation.z, roller.rotation.w))
let rigid_body = world.createRigidBody(rigidBodyDesc);
let colliderDesc = RAPIER.ColliderDesc.cylinder((roller.length*0.42)/2, roller.radius)
        .setFriction(2)
        .setRestitution(0)
let collider = world.createCollider(colliderDesc, rigid_body);

roller.rigid_body = rigid_body
roller.collider  = collider;
roller.kinematic = true;

rollers.push(roller)
```

I am also creating some boxes that are rounded cuboid shapes:

```
const quat = new THREE.Quaternion();
quat.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),(load.angle+90)*(Math.PI/180));

let rigidBodyDesc       = RAPIER.RigidBodyDesc.dynamic()
        .setTranslation(load_position.x, load_position.y, load_position.z)
        .setRotation(new RAPIER.Quaternion(quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w))
        //.setAngularDamping(1)
        //.setLinearDamping(1)
let rigidBody           = world.createRigidBody(rigidBodyDesc);
let colliderDesc        = RAPIER.ColliderDesc.roundCuboid((load_size.x/2)-0.02, (load_size.y/2)-0.02, (load_size.z/2)-0.02, 0.02)
        .setMass(1)
        //.setRestitution(0)
        //.setFriction(1)
let tote_collider       = world.createCollider(colliderDesc, rigidBody);
load.userData.collider  = tote_collider;
load.userData.dynamic   = true;

load.quaternion.copy(tote_collider.rotation())
```

during the simulation, I am rotating the rollers along their axis like this:

```
roller.rigid_body.setNextKinematicRotation(new RAPIER.Quaternion(roller.rotation.x, roller.rotation.y, roller.rotation.z, roller.rotation.w))
```

So, my problem is this:

- if I don't call any code in my update function except for stepping the simulation, the rollers will throw the box violently off of themselves.
- if I call the 'setNextKinematicRotation' on every roller with a new value, the box will begin to move forward, then stop or move backwards or jitter. This isn't consistent though, sometimes it will move along its merry way.
- if I call 'setNextKinematicRotation' on every roller with the same value over and over again, the box will remain perfectly motionless, like it is supposed to.
- if I don't try to scale the speed with the framerate, the jittering seems to go away, but throwing off of the boxes while stopped continues to happen.

I do not understand where the force to throw the box could be coming from if all the rollers are still. and I don't understand why the box seems to fight itself when all the rollers are moving at the same speed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the physics system, but can it be de-coupled from the visualization system (three.js)? Unless the physics simulation is using information from the 3D environment, it might make the problem easier to debug if you can focus on the raw physics data. Or you might find that it runs correctly, and the scene is introducing a variable that is not accounted for.

Comment: thanks for the response, after a lot of trial and error I was able to figure it out. The problem was that if the framerate of the three.js scene dropped below a certain amount, then the roller would have done approximately one whole revolution per frame. So, from the box's perspective, the roller was jittering back and forth even though it appeared motionless.

Kind of like recording a video of helicopter blades that seem motionless on film even though they are spinning at high rpms.

I had to add a check in the code and stop scaling the rolling speed with time for low framerates.